# Scalatest: Combine Assertions

Tags: scala, testing, scalatest

I've just started using WordSpec and I've come across a problem I can't get around.

I'd like to assert on two separate values in one unit test. Suppose I have `val result1` and `val result2`, I need the first to take on a particular value AND the second to take on another particular value.

This would be really easy if it was possible to concatenate/reduce/fold on assertions but I don't think I can. Perhaps something like this:

```
result1 should be (1) ++ result2 should be (2)
```

The result would be a new assertion which is only true if both assertions are true.

If I write them as below, it will only take the last value.

```
result1 should be (1)
result2 should be (2)
```

Does anyone know a way around this?

Comment: If you add one assertion after another it will check both of them, so I don't really understand you problem. You could maybe try `(result1, result2) shouldBe (1,2)`?

Comment: AFAIK scalatest executes all assertions. So you can write it the way you show them. **ScalaTest** is a very complex DSL, it doesn't work like most scala functions were just the las value is returned.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez how do you get scalatest to execute all assertions? My scalatests stop after they hit the first failed assertion. The only way I could find to get scalatest to run all assertions is to wrap the assertions in a [`Checkpoint`](http://doc.scalatest.org/3.0.1/index.html#org.scalatest.Checkpoints). What did you do?

Comment: @skrueger that was the point, that it would start to run all of them and return the first failure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For ScalaTest 3.0.1, the two options I see are:

1.) Use a tuple (as @krzysztof-atłasik has commented)

```scala
(result1, result2) should be (1, 2)
```

2.) Use a [`Checkpoint`](http://doc.scalatest.org/3.0.1/index.html#org.scalatest.Checkpoints)

```scala
val cp = new Checkpoint()

cp { result1 should be (1) }
cp { result2 should be (2) }

cp.reportAll()
```

> class Checkpoint, which enables multiple assertions to be performed within a test, with any failures accumulated and reported together at the end of the test.

-- ScalaTest's Checkpoints scaladoc

Personally, I like `Checkpoint` because it provides an arguably better separation on what is being asserted. However, a potential downside I found is that unlike `should be (x)`, which returns `Assertion`, `Checkpoint#reportAll()` returns `Unit`. I had a method that needed to return `Assertion` and the work around I used was to return [`org.scalatest.Succeeded`](http://doc.scalatest.org/3.0.1/index.html#org.scalatest.Succeeded$).

e.g.,

```scala
def someMethod(): Assertion = {
  ...
  cp.reportAll()
  Succeeded
}
```